# event.clientY is undefined when I put it into a setInterval loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a script for moving an element on a page, and I need to put it in a loop while the mouse and down and is moving, or else there's no way to stop it. But as soon as I put it in a `setInterval` loop for some reason I get this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientY' of undefined'. I don't know why this is happening. Anyone shed some light on the situation?

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '#moveMe', function(){
    $(document).on('mousemove', '#moveMe', function(){
        var inLoop = setInterval(function(){
            var y = event.clientY;
            var x = event.clientX;
            $('#moveMe').css('left', parseInt(x)+"px");
            $('#moveMe').css('top', parseInt(y)+"px");
        }, 1);
        $(document).on('mouseup', 'body', function(){
            clearInterval(inLoop);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The error is "clientY is undefined"? Are you sure it's not something like "Can not read property clientY of undefined"?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientY' of undefined

Comment: `window.event` will become undefined after the event finishes firing. Try changing to `$(document).on('mousemove', '#moveMe', function(event){`

Comment: Do you realise that you will be starting hundreds of intervals? As you are starting one new for each mouse movement, moving an element across the screen will cause one new interval to start each time the element moves a pixel. Drag an element around for a few seconds, and watch the browser grind to a halt, or crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the event to the event handler

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '#moveMe', function(){
    $(document).on('mousemove', '#moveMe', function(event){
        var inLoop = setInterval(function(){
            var y = event.clientY;
            var x = event.clientX;
            $('#moveMe').css('left', parseInt(x)+"px");
            $('#moveMe').css('top', parseInt(y)+"px");
        }, 1);

        $(document).on('mouseup', 'body', function(){
            clearInterval(inLoop);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Making the event var local instead of relying on the global `event` will solve the issue megawac mentioned.